# $ G $ is supersoluble if and only if $ G $ is $ p $-supersoluble for every prime $ p $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I much thought about $ p $-supersoluble but i can't conclude $ G $ is supersoluble if and only if $ G $ is $ p $-supersoluble for every prime $ p $. How to show this is true ?

Comment: What is your definition of p-supersoluble group? I guess a p-supersoluble group is a supersoluble group which factors are p-groups, am i right?

Comment: No, a $p$-supersoluble group is a (finite) group in which the chief factors are either of order $p$ or a $p'$-group.